# Background thread and multitasking in ios?

Tags: ios, upload, fetch, multitasking, background-thread

I am a newbie to iOS. I have a requirement where I need to fetch data from a local database and upload it to a server. This has to be done in the background when the internet connection is available. How can I proceed on this? I need a kick start.

I read that I can achieve this with help of NSThread, or GCD, but I don't get when each of those is most  suitable. Can someone suggest the right way? A sample or pseudocode would help a lot.

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

here is what gcd code should look like:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue_name", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(){
    // code
});
```

Since GCD uses blocks it allows you to capture the state of the local variables.

FYI: You might have searched on Google before posting to stackoverflow. Your query is very common and has been answered before. You might also consider looking at the apple documentation.

Comment: here is the apple link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1